# PHP JQuery Ajax change button val during processing FTP download

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, ftp

I've got a PHP table grid listing a few files that need to be downloaded manually from time to time. I'd prefer to have the "download from ftp" button show whats happening rather than going to a dedicated page to handle the download. I don't need a percentage indicator. I simply want the value of the button to change 3 times, ie:

- Connecting to ftp
- Downloading file
- Download complete

To do this, I'm using JQuery Ajax, but don't know whats the best practice way of executing this.

Here is the button and JQuery Ajax code:

```
<input id="submit_1" type="submit" value="download from ftp" name="submit_1">
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#submit_1').click(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'ajax.php',
                    dataType: 'html',
                    data: {
                        a: 'ftp_download',
                        file_id: 1
                      },
                    success: function(txt){
                        $('#submit_1').val('download complete');
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
```

ajax.php will contain something like this:

```
//#STEP 1 - Connect to FTP
             #set up basic connection
             $ftp_connection = ftp_connect($ftp_host,$ftp_port,$ftp_timeout);

             #login with username and password
             $login_result = ftp_login($ftp_connection, $ftp_username, $ftp_password);

//#STEP 2 - Download File                 
             #try to download $server_file_path and save to $local_file_path
             if (ftp_get($ftp_connection, $local_file_path, $server_file_path, FTP_BINARY)) {
      //#STEP 3 - Download complete
                return true;
             }else{
                return false;
             }

             #close the connection
             ftp_close($ftp_connection);
```

How can I change the value of the submit button while the php script is processing? IE: While connecting to FTP, show "Connecting to FTP". After that step, the download starts, at which point the button value can change to "downloading file"..

Is it possible to update the button from within ajax.php, or does it need to be done in the `<script>... $.ajax...</script>` part?

I've considered breaking the PHP file into 2 parts (1 to test FTP connection, next to download file), then using 2 Ajax calls, one to connect to FTP, then if thats successful, continue to step 2 (maybe passing on the success message from step 1 to step 2, so I dont have to reconnect to ftp in step 2).. but I dont think thats very good coding practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I make two php file :

- The one to perform the download and log the step into a file
- The second to check the file, updating the status and cleanning.

In your javascript :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#submit_1').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'ajax.php',
            dataType: 'html',
            data: {
                a: 'ftp_download',
                file_id: 1
              },
            success: function(txt){

            }
        });
        checkStatus(1);
    });
});

function checkStatus(idFile)
{
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'check_status.php',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data: {
            file_id: idFile
          },
        success: function(response) {
            $('#submit_1').val(response.message);
            if (response.done != true) {
                setTimeout("checkStatus(" + idFile + ")", 1000);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

PHP performing download :

```
<?php

$fileHash = md5($_POST['file_id']);

//#STEP 1 - Connect to FTP
file_put_contents($fileHash, json_encode(array('message' => 'Connecting', 'done' => false)));
$ftp_connection = ftp_connect($ftp_host,$ftp_port,$ftp_timeout);
if ($ftp_connection === false) {
    file_put_contents($fileHash, json_encode(array('message' => 'Connection error', 'done' => true)));
}
$login_result = ftp_login($ftp_connection, $ftp_username, $ftp_password);
if ($ftp_connection === false) {
    file_put_contents($fileHash, json_encode(array('message' => 'Login error', 'done' => true)));
}          

//#STEP 2 - Download File  
file_put_contents($fileHash, json_encode(array('message' => 'Downloading', 'done' => false)));
if (ftp_get($ftp_connection, $local_file_path, $server_file_path, FTP_BINARY)) {
    file_put_contents($fileHash, json_encode(array('message' => 'Download complete', 'done' => true)));
} else {
    file_put_contents($fileHash, json_encode(array('message' => 'Download error', 'done' => true)));
}
ftp_close($ftp_connection);
```

PHP check_status

```
<?php

$response = array('message' => 'Connecting', 'done' => false);
$fileHash = md5($_POST['file_id']);

if (file_exists($fileHash)) {
    $response = json_decode(file_get_contents($fileHash));
    if ((bool) $response->done === true) {
        // Clean the file
        unlink($fileHash);
    }
}

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: I had to make 2 changes in check_status.php,1: line 3, 'status' to 'message'. 2: line 7, $file_get_contents to file_get_contents. Thank you so much, it works fantastically

Comment: It was a pleasure ! I have updated my answer according to your feedback.

Comment: I'm adding cool features now, like changing the colour of the button depending on the message, ie: grey for connecting, orange for downloading, green for complete. Gonna also try get the file size currently downloaded, then compare it to original file size, so I can say Downloading (30%) .. I know I said I didnt want a progress, but hey, if not, why not!.. so impressed man, really awesome script